# Problema con el COPY del dockerfile, Path no encontrado

Tags: docker

Estoy teniendo un problema al momento de hacer el COPY con multi-stage, estoy ejecutando el comando:

```
COPY --from=base /app/path ruta_destino
```

pero al momento de hacer el copy no encuentra la ruta /app/path pero si esta creada y los permisos también.

```
Error: error building at STEP "COPY --from=base /app/path ruta_destino": checking on sources under "/home/build/.build/share/containers/storage/vfs/dir/number": copier: stat: "/app/path": no such file or directory
time="" level=error msg="exit status 125"
```

Pero no entiendo la razón del porque me dice que no la encuentra, les agradecería de antemano cualquier comentario relacionado a ello.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de como funciona el **WORKDIR** el cual soluciona el problema al momento de ejecutar el **COPY**

```
# Stage 1: Compile and Build angular codebase

# Use official node image as the base image
FROM node:10.15.3 as build
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
# Generate the build of the application
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server
FROM nginx:1.17

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /code

COPY --from=build /app/dist .

EXPOSE 8080:8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Hola EnocPineadaA, muchas gracias por su respuesta. Si tengo un workdir despues del FROM (WORKDIR /app), pero el WORKDIR del code (WORKDIR /code) no lo tengo, ese es necesario?

Comment: Si vas a utilizar nginx te recomiendo agregarlo, ese DockerFile me funcionó para desplegar una aplicación Angular.